# Expand compact xml representation to more verbose representation using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm trying to learn xslt as a hobby, and one of the use cases I'm interested is in the expansion of definitions of certain components to their complete forms.  An example should clarify what I mean.  e.g. if my input xml looks like:

```
<universe>
    <galaxies>
         <galaxy name="milky way">
             <system name="solar system"/>
         </galaxy>
         <galaxy name="lactose free">
             <system name="windmill system"/>
         </galaxy>
        <galaxy name="parallelish solar system">
            <system name="the earth system"/>
        </galaxy>
    </galaxies>
    <systems>
        <system name="solar system">
            <planet name="pluto"/>
            <system name="the earth system"/>
            <planet name="mercury"/>
        </system>
        <system name="windmill system">
            <planet name="windy"/>
        </system>
        <system name="the earth system">
            <planet name="earth"/>
            <satellite name="moon"/>
        </system>
    </systems>
</universe>
```

My output xml would have these system definitions expanded in the galaxy definitions recursively (e.g. the earth system in the solar system) and in every single place the definition occurs (e.g. the earth system occurs in two different systems).  The systems section would be removed:

```
<universe>
    <galaxies>
        <galaxy name="milky way">
            <system name="solar system">
                <planet name="pluto"/>
                <system name="the earth system">
                    <planet name="earth"/>
                    <satellite name="moon"/>
                </system>
                <planet name="mercury"/>
            </system>
        </galaxy>
        <galaxy name="lactose free">
            <system name="windmill system">
                <planet name="windy"/>
            </system>
        </galaxy>
        <galaxy name="parallelish solar system">
            <system name="the earth system">
                <planet name="earth"/>
                <satellite name="moon"/>
            </system>
        </galaxy>
    </galaxies>
</universe>
```

I'm pretty much new to xslt, and as of now, the line of thought I've followed has been to somehow define these component blocks as variables and to insert them as appropriate in a (second?) pass.  However, as I've googled around and read a bit trying to find examples, I haven't been very successful.  I'm wondering if this is at all possible (I would expect so), and what concepts I would need to use to achieve this.  Example snippets would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT has a very useful [keys](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key) mechanism for resolving cross-references. To demonstrate how it could work, I have first modified your XML example to avoid circular references:

**XML**

```
<universe>
    <galaxies>
         <galaxy name="milky way">
             <system-ref name="solar system"/>
         </galaxy>
         <galaxy name="lactose free">
             <system-ref name="windmill system"/>
         </galaxy>
        <galaxy name="parallelish solar system">
            <system-ref name="the earth system"/>
        </galaxy>
    </galaxies>
    <systems>
        <system name="solar system">
            <planet name="pluto"/>
            <system-ref name="the earth system"/>
            <planet name="mercury"/>
        </system>
        <system name="windmill system">
            <planet name="windy"/>
        </system>
        <system name="the earth system">
            <planet name="earth"/>
            <satellite name="moon"/>
        </system>
    </systems>
</universe>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="system-by-name" match="system" use="@name" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="system-ref">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('system-by-name', @name)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="systems"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<universe>
   <galaxies>
      <galaxy name="milky way">
         <system name="solar system">
            <planet name="pluto"/>
            <system name="the earth system">
               <planet name="earth"/>
               <satellite name="moon"/>
            </system>
            <planet name="mercury"/>
         </system>
      </galaxy>
      <galaxy name="lactose free">
         <system name="windmill system">
            <planet name="windy"/>
         </system>
      </galaxy>
      <galaxy name="parallelish solar system">
         <system name="the earth system">
            <planet name="earth"/>
            <satellite name="moon"/>
         </system>
      </galaxy>
   </galaxies>
</universe>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Michael!  I am starting to read about keys now, thanks for pointing them out.

Comment: I also found that for my particular case, it feels more 'natural' to distinguish between systems/system (definition) vs. system references implicitly by using the original xml I posted, and the following more specific template match:

    <xsl:template match="system/system|galaxy/system">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="key('system-by-name', @name)"/>
    </xsl:template>
I do have reading up to do about excluding matches too (e.g. not(system/systems)).